# How to have the 2nd option in a Spinner selected by default?

Tags: android, android-spinner

because of my assignment to recreate an application as much as possible, I cannot change the spinner item order (unless what I'm about to ask is impossible in Android).

I populate the spinner using values from a String[]. When the iOS version is run, the top choice is not selected by default, but the second item is. I want to keep the same order, so I wanted to know if it would be possible to have the spinner display the second option upon the opening of the activity it resides in.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (mySpinner.getCount() > 1) // if there are at least two items
mySpinner.setSelection(1); // select the second item
```

You can use this after you set the adapter.